# Как типизировать функцию в vitest, что бы можно было вызвать у нее метод mockReturnValue?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, юнит-тесты, vite

Имеется вот такой вот тест

```js
it("Closing and opening mobile navigation", async () => {
    // Мокаем данные на отрисовку mobile версии
    (useScreenResolution as Mock).mockReturnValue("mobile");

    render(
      <RenderWithRouter>
        <Sidebar />
      </RenderWithRouter>
    );

    const burgerIcon = screen.getByTestId("burgerIcon"); // Поиск иконки бургера
    expect(burgerIcon).toBeInTheDocument(); // Проверка на сущ
    expect(screen.queryByTestId("sidebar")).toBeNull(); // // Проверка, что sidebar на странице не отрисован

    await userEvent.click(burgerIcon); // Клик по бургеру

    expect(screen.queryByTestId("sidebar")).toBeInTheDocument(); // Проверка, что sidebar отрисован на странице

    const btnCloseSidebar = screen.getByTestId("btnCloseSidebar"); // Кнопка закрытия sidebar
    expect(btnCloseSidebar).toBeInTheDocument(); // Проверка, что

    await userEvent.click(btnCloseSidebar); // Клик на иконку закрытия sidebar

    expect(screen.queryByTestId("sidebar")).toBeNull; // Проверка, что на странице sidebar отсутствует
  });
```

Как можно правильно типизировать без as Mock, что бы была явная типизация без as

```js
(useScreenResolution as Mock).mockReturnValue("mobile");
```

Что бы я мог у useScreenResolution сразу вызвать mockReturnValue и у него были доступны только значнеия "mobile" и "desktop" как в оригинале